# Why a v2 signed APK can be upgraded by a v1 signed APK?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an APK which was signed by V2 signature in version 1.0. Later, I released a 2.0 version APK which is signed by V1 signature and I found I am able to upgrade the APK from 1.0 to 2.0. Both of the versions are using the same `.keystore` and `ks-pass` file. What I don't understand is why the APK can be used to upgrade even they are using different signature method. Is this correct behaviour or did I do anything wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use the older signing implementation? Why not stick with V2?

Comment: The app signed with v2 is already deployed to production and we are going to create a new app which support old version of android OS who doesn't support v2 signature.